# Windows batch file 'for' loop solution

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I would like to write a `FOR` loop in a batch file to create some variables.

I'm setting up variables in a menu that has 60 options. Variables `item1` to `item60` contain menu items some of which are empty. The variable `%pad%` contains 40 spaces. So the following code ensures that each menu item `dis1` to `dis60` is 40 characters long.

```bash
set dis1=%item1%%pad%
set dis1=%dis1:~0,40%
```

So the problem is I need to repeat this code 60 times as follows:

```bash
set dis1=%item1%%pad%
set dis1=%dis1:~0,40%
```

To...

```bash
set dis60=%item60%%pad%
set dis60=%dis60:~0,40%
```

Please could you tell me a `FOR` loop to accomplish this task. I'm not sure how to increment the 1-60 value since it's inside a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /L %%e IN (1,1,12) DO SET "dis%%e=item %%e"
SET "pad=           wxyz"
FOR /L %%e IN (1,1,12) DO (
 SET "dis%%e=!dis%%e!%pad%"
 SET "dis%%e=!dis%%e:~0,20!"
)
FOR /L %%e IN (1,1,12) DO ECHO !dis%%e!

ENDLOCAL

SETLOCAL
FOR /L %%e IN (1,1,12) DO SET "dis%%e=item %%e"
SET "pad=           wxyz"
FOR /L %%e IN (1,1,12) DO CALL :padme dis%%e
FOR /L %%e IN (1,1,12) DO CALL ECHO %%dis%%e%%

GOTO :EOF

:padme
CALL SET "%1=%%%1%%%pad%"
CALL SET "%1=%%%1:~0,20%%"

GOTO :eof
```

Here's two methods, one using `delayedexpansion` and the other with delayedexpansion disabled (default condition) [Stephan's DELAYEDEXPANSION link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947)

I added a few characters to the end of the `pad` variable to show that the added characters are properly truncated. Obviously, the number should be changed to suit your situation. The demo ones I used are for a manageable output.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution, it has been so helpful.